# How can create a generic type that is a combination of other types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

Let's say I want to create a `UserResponse` type that looks something like this:

```js
type UserResponse = {
  data: User,
  meta: Meta
}
```

How could i make the `Response` type more generic so that I don't have to recreate the same structure for other response types where only the type of the `data` property changes?

So that creating a new type would look something like follows:

```js
type ArticleResponse = Response<Article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

```
interface Response<T> {
    data: T,
    meta: Meta
}

type ArticleResponse = Response<Article>;
type UserResponse = Response<User>;
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it somehow possible to make the `key` generic as well? E.g. change the `data` key `user` or `article`

Comment: @icalvin102: That's a separate (much harder) question. I don't know of a way, but typescript continually surprises me.